# Why I get error Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I use `ng-repeat`:

```
<option ng-selected="key == formData.city" ng-repeat="(key, value) in data.cities | orderBy:value" value="{{key}}">{{value}}</option>
```

`data.cities` is array.

Also I have method that gets array of cities from AJAX response and sets it to exists array `$scope.data.cities`:

```
request.success(function (data) {
      var arr = []
      angular.forEach(data.res, function(item) {
      arr[item.id] = item.name;
      });

  $scope.data.cities = arr;
});
```

Why after response I get error: `[ngRepeat:dupes]`?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `track by $index` with your `ng-repeat` to avoid duplicates:

```
ng-repeat="(key, value) in data.cities track by $index | orderBy:value"
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes

**Update:**
You memory leak might be a reason of using array:

```
var arr = [];
```

For example, if your cities.id looks like `1001` this will produce an array with 1000 empty items and one with your city.

In your situation I would recommend to use an `Object` instead of `Array`:

```
request.success(function (data) {
    var obj = {};
    angular.forEach(data.res, function(item) {
       obj[item.id] = item.name;
    });

    $scope.data.cities = obj;
});
```

Also, you can replace `ng-repeat` with `ng-options` here:

```
<select ng-model="formData.city" ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in data.cities">
```

Comment: This disables my web page and takes a lot RAM over 500 mb

Comment: Over 3000 items. I tried you solution, does not help me

Comment: @Hamed, it sounds like too much for one time, I would say, you may try to decrease the number of items and see what happens